# When to close hbase connection and what will happen if connection not closed

Tags: scala, hbase

Am new to hbase. I want to perform 2 scan operation on different tables.
So i have return genetic function to scan and closed the connection at end in scala.

fuctionhbasescan(Tablename1, scanfield)
fuctionhbasescan(Tablename2, scanfield)

when I call the function for tablename 1 it worked fine and returned result.
But when i called the same function for tablename 2, it says connection closed.

Is that only one connection is established for the instance in scala ? we need to close the connection in end of process in driver?

Please help me to understand the connection process and how it works.

Note:(HConnectionManager)connection established using connectionfactory.createconnection and then connection.getTable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure based on info provided, but the connection may have been closed by the first function. You can

- Check if the connection `isClosed` as documented 
  https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html
  and if necessary, create another connection with `createConnection` (see
  https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ConnectionFactory.html )
- Avoid closing the connection until you're done with it. Move the `close` call on the connection outside of the inner function call, and wait until both scans are done, to close the connection.